# Gap/margin issue with Firefox/IE

Tags: css, firefox

I wish to have a bunch of rectangles containing text, sitting next to each other, and wrapping to the next line where necessary. I have a maximum width for each rectangle, and any text that doesn't fit inside the rectangle should be hidden.

Here is the code I have written

#### HTML

```
<div id="outer">
    <ul id="list">
        <li>The name of soemthing</li>
        <li>Something else</li>
        <li>Something else 2</li>
        <li>Something else 3 </li>
        <li>Something else 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#outer {
    background-color: #0000ff;
    width: 500px;
}

#list {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#list li {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #ff0000;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

It works perfectly in Chrome.

In Firefox/IE, there is a small vertical gap/margin added between each rectangle.

I can make the gap go away by removing the 'overflow: hidden' on the LI elements, but this ofcourse allows rectangles to grow freely - which is what im trying to avoid.

Anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting all the `<li>` tags on the same line.  The browsers are rendering the line break as white space.

```
<div id="outer">
    <ul id="list">
        <li>The name of soemthing</li><li>Something else</li><li>Something else 2</li><li>Something else 3</li><li>Something else 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use floated **block** elements instead or do they have to be **inline-block** elements?

Here's [your example](http://jsfiddle.net/7bVTd/), and here's [the code working](http://jsfiddle.net/7bVTd/2/) with shrink-wrapped floating elements.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add `vertical-align: top` to `#list li`: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/PF4fW/

*Every* time you use `display: inline-block`, you should consider setting `vertical-align`.

[Look at "Series A" here](http://www.brunildo.org/test/inline-block.html) to compare the different possible common values.